# Data Studio date range that filter on Google Sheet Column

Tags: google-sheets, filtering, date-range, looker-studio

I'm using Google Sheets, and wanted to do a Data Studio "real time" report, based on the data in the sheet.
The sheet contains data from an issue management program.

My data in the sheet exactly:
Issue type (string), Work time (number), issue created at (date), issue resolved at (date)

I successfully created a pie chart that's dimension is: Issue type and metric: Work time
I can see that all the data in the pie chart.

Now my problem is:
I can't filter this chart with a date range.
The date is in a correct format: YYYYMMDD
but I can't describe to data studio, which date column it should filter when I set a date range in the control.

Is it possible some way to create two date range filter and one of them filter on created date, and the other one filter on resolved at date?

Thank all of you!
Roland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I deleted the connection between the sheet and the report, and started again everything, and it works fine. I think I created the connection when the date was not in a correct format, I changed it after making the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that the date range you're filtering by is the first date column from the left in your Sheet. If it's not, then Data Studio gets confused and doesn't work properly.

I'm not sure if you can have two different dates in two different filters. The graphs wouldn't know which filter to follow.

Comment: Thanks! I finally figured it out, that the order of things matter here. I deleted the chart, the date filter and the connection between the sheet and the report. I started again from making the connection put the controllers on the riport. I raised that a date dimension appears in the chart's settings and the date range filter works fine.